# Tomcat 9 JMX RMI authentication vulnerability

Tags: java, tomcat

I am pretty new to Java and Tomcat but we have no one else that has any clue on either one so I get to try and remedy the issue.

We are recently upgrading from Tomcat 8 to Tomcat 9.  I am trying to enable authentication due to a Qualys open vulnerability of JMX RMI accessible with common credentials.  I have the following settings defined in the Java Options:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8080
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\lib\management\jmxremote.password
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\lib\management\jmxremote.access
```

I currently have both Tomcat 8 and Tomcat 9 installed.  They are both using the same Java Options.  However, when I start the Tomcat 9 service, I get a error 1067 about the process terminating unexpectedly.

Tomcat 8 with the same setting starts and runs fine.  If I set the option to authenticate to false, Tomcat 9 has no problems starting and running.  Is there any additional Java Options that I need to add with Tomcat 9 that I did not need with Tomcat 8?

This is only needed to close the Qualys vulnerability.  The server does not actually need to connect using JMX remotely.

Comment: The difference in behaviour you describe doubtfully has any connection with Tomcat. Are you using the same JRE on both servers?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of response.

Comment: The same JRE is used for both Tomcat 8 and Tomcat 9.  I still have both services installed on the same server.  Tomcat 9 service will indeed work as long as I do not set jmxremote.authenticate to true.  Once I set it to true, is when I get the error.  At first I thought it was issues with the password and access files, but the same exact Java Options work with the Tomcat 8 service we have installed on the same server.  It is a direct copy and paste of the Java Options on both services(for the jmxremote options only)

Comment: I just noticed now: isn't port 8080 used also by Tomcat 9's HTTP connector? Can you provide some logs?

Comment: I really do not know if port 8080 is used differently on Tomcat 8 and 9.  Which logs should I get?  Like I said, I am still very new at Java/Tomcat.  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Look into `logs/catalina.<date>.log`.

Comment: It looks like it is working now for some reason.....I dont think I changed anything, just tried starting the service one more time to generate the logs, and it started up like it should.  Thanks for the help!